# the inner join to the same table twice(ALIASES)

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have an issue with my inner join,these are my tables with `FK` and `PK`

```
TABLE CITY
city_id (PK)
city_name
state

TABLE DEPOT
dep_id (PK)
capacity
city_id (FK) references CiTy

TABLE MANUFACTURER
manu_id (PK)
manu_name
city_id (FK) references city
```

so I just want to make the result look like this:

`DEPOT_CITY_name(references from city_id)`, `MANUFACTURER_CITY_name(references from city_id)`

so `depot_city_name` will show the `name of city` from `depo` (`references CITY.city_id`)

and `manufacturer_city_name` will show the `name of city` from `manufacturer` (`references CITY.city_id`)

thanks

Comment: Is there any relation-ship between depot & manufacturer table?

Comment: nope, theres no relationship between depot and manufacturer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a left outer join:

```
select c.city_id, d.depo_id, m.manu_id,c.city_name
from city c
left outer join depo d on c.city_id=d.city_id
left outer join manufacturer m on c.city_id=m.city_id
```

**EDIT:** if you want to separate the city name for depo and manufacturer then use:

```
select c.city_id, d.depo_id, m.manu_id,
case 
when  d.depo_id is null then null else c.city_name end DEPOT_CITY_name,
case 
when m.manu_id is null then null else c.city_name end manufacturer_city_name 
from city c
left outer join depo d on c.city_id=d.city_id
left outer join manufacturer m on c.city_id=m.city_id
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply, but the results only displays the city from depo, i need to display the city from manufacturer as well.

Comment: the city you see in the answer is common for both depo and manufacturer if their ids exists in the result, but if for example the manu_id is null and depo_id is not null then city_name is for depo

Comment: is that possible to display them in 2 different columns?

Comment: yes of course, answer edited, hope it be helpful

Comment: thanks very much for ur help. and one more thing, is that possible if we use inner join instead of left outer join?

Comment: you are very welcome, you can accept the answer if it helped of was useful

Comment: it depends on type of your relationship, inner join is good for one-to-one, but here you have one-to-many and it's better to use outer joins, I mean if you use inner join you may lost some result i.e: if for a specific city, manufacturer exists but depo not exists

Comment: do you mind to show me how to use inner join in this case? appreciate your help

Comment: just remove the "left outer"s and instead of case statements just use c.city_name, but it may give you incorrect results if you have for example a city which have manufacturer but not depo

Comment: do you mind to explain it with the code? im a newbie at sql. thanks

Comment: select c.city_id,d.depo_id, m.manu_id,c.city_name depo_city, c.city_name manufacturer_city, 
from city c
join depo d on c.city_id=d.city_id
join manufacturer m on c.city_id=m.city_id  ,but as I told this may give you incomplete result